# how to get used text details on gimp

Tags: fonts, gimp, font-size, font-weight

How can i get used text details like font-family,font-size,font-weight etc from a psd file in gimp

[image: Psd file sample]

Comment: We would appreciate any hints about how PSD does actually store that information - this is not easily derived from the PSD file format specification, or at least I've never been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done, the PSD text layers are converted to bitmap in Gimp and the text information is lost.